# get only filtered data in Twitter Bootstrap 2 datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-plugins, datatable

i have 100 records in my `jquery data table` and i am getting count of records like below

```
var oSOTable = $('#tblMultiSelectListWO_SO_DET').dataTable();
var dataArraySO = oSOTable.fnGetData();
var length =  dataArraySO.length;
```

now what my need is, i have filtered my data table using the `simple search` of the data table, now i have only 5 records. i `need only the filtered data and it's count`. tried the same above code but still it giving same old count. can anyone help me?

tried this answer got from SO, but that also not working.

```
var dataArraySO = oSOTable.fnGetFilteredData();
```

Comment: Datatable form rows on the fly, and it creates only those html rows which are visible. You cannot read total row by just counting total tr available in the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i am using `Twitter Bootstrap 2 datatable`. For the above problom i tried `dataTable()._('tr', {"filter": "applied"})` , `fnGetFilteredNodes` etc but unfortunately none of that worked for me! 
so finally this is what i done for getting all filtered data from data table, which is very simple.

```
$("#tblDataTable tr").each(function(x,tr) 
{
    var data = $.trim($(tr).find('td').eq(1).html()); // eq(n)      
});
```

**NOTE**: hided columns in datatable cant access through this code beacause hided columns are not in DOM.